# drush error message: CiviCRM: System: Please specify a realistic site URL (Ex: drush -l http://example.com:456 ...)

Tags: drupal, drush

After upgrading Drupal from 8.9 to 9.2 for several weeks I always get following error message when I use the command

```
drush upgradedb

CiviCRM: System: Please specify a realistic site URL (Ex: drush -l  http://example.com:456 ...)
```

When I ignore this message I can execute the upgradedb-command, but I still don't know whether this message points to some important information. I have no idea where I should specify the url.

Has anybody any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify it in the command, e.g.

`drush -l https://my-site.org upgradedb`

For upgradedb it shouldn't be too important, but for example for a command that sends out emails with links it would have `http://default/` in them instead of your real site.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved the matter for me.